# How to bypass Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have seen couple of apps like [LikeHero](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/likehero-boost-your-social/id814632912?mt=8) and [LikeBoost](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/like-boost-get-more-instagram/id883915744?mt=8) which makes users to exchange likes for instagram. If you try to login, it doesnt authenticates via Instagram. They ask your username and password and bypass the API. How do they do it ?

Could anyone please enlighten me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

They are collecting username and password and automating login and other tasks on android phones.